# How do I stop an emailed form from scrolling left/right when viewing in Outlook 2010?

Tags: form, outlook, datepicker

I have an InfoPath form that when submitted sends an email. When the email is viewed i have to scroll left/right to see all the data. I have tried setting the field sizes to a set PX but the Date Picker field always expands across the page.
If I take the Date Picker field out the form view is ok, but I need to have a Date Picker (or equivalent) on the form.
Any ideas on why this is happening & how I can stop it?